# Convert file to Windows-1257 encoding via power shell

Tags: c#, file, powershell, encoding

how could I convert all the files in the folder to Windows-1257 encoding? I have this code which does it to UTF8 encoding:

```
$Dir="D:\Data\eip_orders\new_utf8\"
$Dir2="D:\Data\eip_orders\new_test\"

foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.eip")){ 
   "Converting $item..." 
   $MyFile = Get-Content $Dir$item
   $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)
   [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines(($Dir+$item.name), $MyFile, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
} 

foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.eip")){
   "Moving $item..." 
   Move-Item $Dir$item $Dir2$item
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

I need the similar with Windows-1257.

```
$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.windows-1257($False)
```

is not working.

Also tried:`$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.GetEncoding(1257)`

But then I get "Cannot find type [System.Text.GetEncoding]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded."

Comment: Have you checked the [MSDN Documentation for System.Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text(v=vs.110).aspx) and specifically for the [subclass System.Text.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Encoding.Convert comes in particularly handy

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the encoding using Encoding.GetEncoding(1257), no idea how to get that particular encoding.

Comment: `$Utf8NoBomEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1257)`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Dir="D:\Data\eip_orders\new_utf8\"
$Dir2="D:\Data\eip_orders\new_test\"

foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.eip")){ 
   "Converting $item..." 
   $MyFile = Get-Content $Dir$item
   $Utf8NoBomEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1257)
   [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines(($Dir+$item.name), $MyFile, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
} 

foreach($item in (dir $Dir "*.eip")){
   "Moving $item..." 
   Move-Item $Dir$item $Dir2$item
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
```

This seems to work fine, thanks!